# is twitter4j still functional for twitter APIv1.1?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I want to use java servlets to call the latest twitter API V1.1 that integrates the oAut 1.0 protocol and I would want to know if twitter4j is still functional?

Comment: Have you tried Googling?

Comment: i did but in most of the threads people were't in agreement

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! twitter4j is still functional !